# assign id to jquery dialog button

Tags: jquery, button, dialog

How do i assign an  an id to a jquery dialog button. I tried the following but it's not working

```
buttons: {
Ok: function() {
id="xyz",
...
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The following (seemingly undocumented) works for me with jQuery 1.8.9:

```
$("#dlg").dialog({
  buttons :  { 
     "MyButton" : {
         text: "My Button",
         id: "my-button-id",
         click: function(){
             alert("here");
         }   
      } 
   }
});
```

The button can be addressed via $("#my-button-id")

Comment: This *is* documented: "Each element of the array must be an object defining the *attributes*, properties, and event handlers to set on the button." ID is a standard attribute.

Answer (score 20):

**This code from official site worked for me:**

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    // properties ... 
    buttons: [{
        id:"btn-accept",
        text: "Accept",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, 
    {
        id:"btn-cancel",
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "code from official site"? The official documentation for dialog buttons does not say that `id` is a valid property: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons In fact, it implies the opposite by saying "if you need access to the button, it is available as the target of the event object". If `id` were a valid property, it would obviously also be possible to access the button with it. Undocumented "features" can get dropped unexpectedly, such as in this case: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4437 So this answer wrongly implies that `id` is officially supported.

Comment: It doesn't explicitly state that ID is supported, but it most definitely doesn't imply the opposite. It says:"Each element of the array must be an object defining the *attributes*, properties, and event handlers to set on the button."
ID is a standard attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
buttons: {
    'MyButton': function() {
        //... configure the button's function
    }
```

And the id setter

```
$('button:contains(MyButton)').attr("id","xyz");
```

Answer (score 3):

@BerndB: Thanks it works perfectly and even is more extendable.

```
$('#loginlink').live('click',function(){
    DC = 'login_box';
    diaOpt = {
        autoOpen : true,
        width : 400,
        title : 'Login',
        buttons: {
            //valiudate login
            'Login' : {
                text : 'Login Now',
                id : 'validateForm',
                click : function(){
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    launchDialog(diaOpt, DC);
});

$('#validateForm').live('click', function(){
    alert('Hellop');
    $("#loginform").validate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#OK",{id:'xyz'});
```

hope that it helps

Comment: I think this will be enigma to use. Please be a little descriptive.

Comment: I have it like this and it's not assigning the id #OK.
Prev:function(){$("#OK",{id:'xyz'});