# How to set id for an inline JQuery button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign id to an existing buttons on dialog, the buttons are added to the dialog dynamically.

I have tried these ([assign id to jquery dialog button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929394/assign-id-to-jquery-dialog-button)) but didn't work. I am using Jquery 1.11.1 on jsp page

```
<div id='dialog_acknowledgement' title='someTitle' style='display: none;'>
    <span style="text-align:left">
        <p><%=popupMessage%></p>
    </span>
</div>

...

$( 'div#dialog_acknowledgement').dialog( { 
    modal: true, 
    autoOpen: true,
    width: 750,
    position: [ 'center', 'center' ],
    open: function() { jQuery( '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close' ).hide(); },
    close: function() { 
            if ($( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val() == "") {
                $( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val( "CANCEL" );
            }
            $( "form[name='page_form']" ).submit();
        },
    buttons: {
        "<%=lh.getText("review_jsp_23", LocalizableTag.CONFIG_MESSAGE, "Cancel")%>": function() {   
            $( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val( "CANCEL" ); // trying to set the id for these buttons
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "<%=lh.getText("review_jsp_27", LocalizableTag.CONFIG_MESSAGE, "ACKNOWLEDGE")%>": function() {
            $( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val( "ACKNOWLEDGE" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
} );
```

This is the generated js when I tried one of the options to set the id

```
buttons: {
    "Cancel": function() {  
        $(this).attr("id","cancelButton_1");                                
        $( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val( "CANCEL" );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        //window.location.href = '../../etm/etmMenu.jsp?selectedTocID=null&parentID=0'
    },
    "ACKNOWLEDGE": function() {
        $( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val( "ACKNOWLEDGE" );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
}
```

This is the html generated, cannot see id's

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
            <span class="ui-button-text">ACKNOWLEDGE</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add id to those buttons, so that I can use them for my selenium test cases

Comment: The $(this) in buttons does not refer to the button but the dialog triggering element itself. That is why there is the $(this).dialog('close'). You can set the id as a property of button itself. Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312835/set-jquery-ui-dialog-button-id

Comment: @NawedKhan I tried this but got an error "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'", this fires on document.ready. I am new to jquery

`buttons: {
                    "<%=lh.getText("gtaAssociateReview_jsp_23", LocalizableTag.CONFIG_MESSAGE, "Cancel")%>": {
                    id:"cancel",
                    function() { 
                        $( 'input[name=acknowledgementAction]' ).val( "CANCEL" );`